# If there are $n$ $Y$'s for every $X$, but $m$ $X$'s for every $Y$, then the total number of $Y$'s is $n/m$ times the number of $X$'s?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

(Apologies for the lengthy title. If you can make it shorter but still descriptive, please do so.)

There is a certain form of reasoning that I find myself using every once in a while. I believe it's a valid argument, but I find it hard to express without reverting to informal, handwavy language. I will illustrate with two examples.

> **Problem:** Given a planar triangulation with $f$ faces and $e$ boundary edges, how many total edges does it have?
>
> **Solution:** Each face is adjacent to three edges, but most edges are adjacent to two faces, so each face only "owns" half of each edge it is adjacent to. But a boundary edge is only adjacent to one face, so the other "half" of it is "unaccounted for". Therefore, the total number of edges is $\frac32f+\frac12e$.

> **Problem:** Give a combinatorial interpretation of $\binom n{k+1}=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\binom nk$.
>
> **Solution:** There are $\binom nk$ permutations of $k$ apples and $n-k$ oranges; call such a permutation a $k$-permutation. Any $k$-permutation can be turned into a $(k+1)$-permutation in $n-k$ ways by replacing one of the $n-k$ oranges with an apple. On the other hand, a $(k+1)$-permutation can be turned into an $k$-permutation by replacing one of the $k+1$ apples with an orange. "Therefore", the number of $(k+1)$-permutations is $\frac{n-k}{k+1}$ times the number of $k$-permutations.

In general, we have a relation $R\subseteq X\times Y$, such that for all $x\in X$ we have $|\{y\in Y:x\mathrel{R}y\}|=n$ and for all $y\in Y$ we have $|\{x\in X:x\mathrel{R} y\}|=m$. We conclude that $|Y|=\frac nm|X|$. In the first example, we only had "most" instead of "all", and consequently we had to include a correction term in the final result.

Does this technique have a name? It's not quite the inclusion-exclusion principle, or the pigeonhole principle, but it feels like a generalization of the handshaking lemma in graph theory. If it doesn't have a standard name, is there an elegant, rigorous, and preferably concise way to express/justify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called double-counting: one way to think of it is that you show $m|Y|=n|X|$, by observing that they represent two ways of counting the cardinality of the same object.